# Date condition in default_scope for a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements, default-scope

I want to ensure that only Movies with a watched date are brought back and ordered by that value in ascending order.

I think I'm fairly close with the following:

```
default_scope :conditions => { :watched_date => not null },
              :order => 'watched_date ASC'
```

But I don't know how to add a condition for a non-null date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work if you change the conditions to this?:

```
:conditions => 'watched_date IS NOT NULL'
```

You might want to include the table name incase this is used in joins like so:

```
:conditions => 'movies.watched_date IS NOT NULL'
```

Comment: I'm afraid not, that prevents any results from coming back.

Comment: I just checked some code where I had done this, and I had messed up the syntax. Just updated my answer with how I've been doing it.